# chrome.i18n.getUILanguage returning empty string

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, internationalization, locale

we are seeing our service getting either empty locale or locale in the format
{language}*{region}*{variant} e.g. zh_CN_#Hans or zh_CN

The only client making call is an chrome extension and we use chrome.i18n.getUILangauge() to get the browser language and pass that as locale.
When we debug we see the value of format {langauge}-{region}-{variant} e.g. zh-CN

Wondering if there are any edge cases where the chrome.i18n.getUILanguage() will every produce empty string or locale in the first format

Thanks

Comment: It's probably a bug in Chrome.

Comment: What is your Google Chrome version number? And on what platform did you experience this issue?
I did the test on Chrome 99.0.4844.74 Mac and can see my "en-GB" as output.